# Jenkins to oracle

Tags: oracle, jenkins

How to configure Jenkins to run Query (select, Update) on Oracle database,

1. Is there any plugin available in Jenkins?
2. Is there any easy way to write script in python?

Comment: You should describe what you want Jenkins to do in your Oracle database. Poll for changes? Alter data as part of a build job? You could of course have a shell build-step that does things in Oracle (via sqlplus for example).

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins is a Continuous Integration (CI) tool. It is a development practice that requires developers to integrate code into a shared repository several times a day. Each check-in is then verified by an automated build, allowing teams to detect problems early.

1. Is there any plugin available in Jenkins?

   > As far as i know, there are no plugins for the type of job you're looking for. However, it *does* provide you a mechanism to run your own scripts by using various options present in `Build` section such as running a Win batch script, shell script, perl, python, ant commands etc...
2. Is there any easy way to write script in python?

   > If you understand the language well, then yes!

This link might be of some interest: `http://176.34.122.30/blog/2009/05/18/continuous-integration-with-oracle-plsql-utplsql-and-hudson/`

Answer (score 2):

Plugin to run Sql on Oracle database in Jenkins:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SQLPlus+Script+Runner+Plugin